# URP Decal Projector - Decal Disappears Depending On Viewing Angle

Tags: unity, unity-urp

**Issue:**

- The Decal that my URP Decal Projector is projecting disappears depending on the viewing angle. (Recording Link at bottom)

---

**Setup:**

- I've added a **URP Decal Projector** by right-clicking in the hierarchy: > Rendering > URP Decal Projector.
- I've created a material to use for it, added the texture I want to use as a Base Map, and set the shader to Shader Graphs/Decal.
- Here's what my Decal Projector GameObject looks like in the Inspector:
  [image]

---

- Here is a recording of me replicating the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNEWnccrDO8

Is anyone familiar with how I can resolve this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that may experience this issue, I switched to a different editor version and this issue has not occurred yet.

More specifically, I was working in version 2022.2.0b2 and switched to 2022.2.0b13. Not sure exactly how that fixed the issue, but maybe changing editor versions will resolve this for someone else.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as "Accepted" if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

by default decal method was set to automatic, which sometime it will be set to screen space, your problem could be the same as me, which could be fix by changing the decal method to dbuffer instead of automatic